# avconv stops converting jpegs to video without proper error message

Tags: jpeg, avconv

I have a problem and I hope someone can help:
I'm trying to convert 287000 jpegs into a video. I tried the following command:

```
avconv -r 360 -i img%06d.jpg -r 30 out.mkv
```

But I also tried it without the framerate options with the same result:

```
img%06d.jpg: Input/output error
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is? The images are all the same format, resolution, etc... but maybe some are corrupt. If this could be the reason for stopping the conversion, is there an option to drop corrupt input images automatically?

Comment: As far as i know there currently is no way to skip or drop corrupt images from the sequence. You can try to use `imagemagic` commands together with a bash script to try to deal with the situation, however.

Comment: One extra question through. Does it begin to convert and then breaks or does it break right away?